# Bounding summation

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Let $T$ be a sufficiently large real number and $\gamma$ be imaginary part of non-trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function. I would like to bound the sum like
$$\sum_{0<\gamma\leq T}\gamma^{-1/4}.$$
I see the paper proceeds as follows. By partial summation, we have
$$\sum_{0<\gamma\leq T}\gamma^{-1/4}=T^{-1/4}N(T)+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{T}t^{-\frac{5}{4}}N(t)dt.$$
Note that, as $T\rightarrow\infty$,
$$N(T)=\sum_{0<\gamma\leq T}1=\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi e}+O(\log T).$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{0<\gamma\leq T}\gamma^{-1/4}\ll T^{3/4}\log T+\int_{1}^{T}t^{-5/4}t\log tdt.
\end{align}
I don't understand why the interval of integration change from [0,T] to [1,T] and why we can use $N(t)=O(t\log t)$ for $1\leq t\leq T$. Could someone please explain this?

Comment: The first non-trivial zero is around $T \approx 14.13$ so $N(T)$ is identically zero for $T \le 14$, so it makes no difference whether the first integral starts at $0$ or $1$ or $3\pi$.  It is mildly convenient to avoid $0$ so that we don’t have to work with a needlessly large $O(\log T)$ term.